# Getting exception in JDO query when using aggregated function with CASE WHEN

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, datanucleus

I'm executing following query in my gae and getting exception.

```
    PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(" select date, vehicleCode, vehicleSubCode, colorCode, ");
    sb.append(" SUM(CASE WHEN transactionType = 0 THEN count ELSE 0 END) stock, ");
    sb.append(" SUM(CASE WHEN transactionType = 1 THEN count ELSE 0 END) sale, ");
    sb.append(" SUM(CASE WHEN transactionType = 2 THEN count ELSE 0 END) transfer ");
    sb.append(" from Stock as AggregatedStock ");

    Query query = pm
            .newQuery(sb.toString());

    query.setFilter(" updatedByDealer == " + dealer);
    query.setGrouping(" date, vehicleCode, vehicleSubCode, colorCode ");
    query.setOrdering(" vehicleCode desc ");

    query.declareImports("import com.sandeepapplabs.dms.Stock");
```

Exception I'm getting is

```
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: ')' expected at character 57 in            "date, vehicleCode, vehicleSubCode, colorCode,  SUM(CASE WHEN transactionType = 0 THEN count ELSE 0 END) -  SUM(CASE WHEN transactionType = 1 THEN count ELSE 0 END) -  SUM(CASE WHEN transactionType = 2 THEN count ELSE 0 END)"
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: ')' expected at character 57 in "date, vehicleCode, vehicleSubCode, colorCode,  SUM(CASE WHEN transactionType = 0 THEN count ELSE 0 END) -  SUM(CASE WHEN transactionType = 1 THEN count ELSE 0 END) -  SUM(CASE WHEN transactionType = 2 THEN count ELSE 0 END)"
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:519)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.execute(JDOQuery.java:230)
at com.sandeepapplabs.dms.AggregatedStockEndpoint.listAggregatedStock(AggregatedStockEndpoint.java:56)
```

Similar query works fine in SQLFiddle

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d9fe1/1)

Comment: since when has JDOQL had a CASE statement? DataNucleus has a "IF ELSE" statement. This is not SQL

Comment: Oops ...... I didn't know that. @Neil Stockton As I'm new to this can you give me any idea about how can I achieve the thing I want in JDOQL. Basically I want to sum(count), something similar to SQLFiddle ex I have provided.

Comment: JDOQL is described on http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_0/jdo/jdoql.html (as well as the JDO spec) but GAE only supports a subset of all of that.